# The Hinduism Stack Exchange Bhashya

Tags: discussion, community

Saturday was the three-year anniversary of our site, and not long before that we passed our 5000 question mark.  I wanted to commemorate all that by making a post illustrating how much of the verses of Hindu scripture has been asked about here.  In a way, the questions of our site form a Bhashya or commentary on many of the scriptures of Hinduism.  So I've compiled all the questions which ask about a specific verse of the Bhagavad Gita or the Brahma Sutras.

I've started with these two scriptures, but if people find other scriptures whose verses have been frequently asked about, I can add those as well.  By the way, this serves multiple purposes: it highlights how far we've come, it encourages people to post more scripture-based questions, and it's a reference for people in future if they're interested in a given scriptural verse.

Comment: Wow! How did we miss 3rd anniversary? Btw, we have done considerable improvement in % answered and QPD comparatively last 2 years.

Comment: How about adding SB and Upanishads?

Comment: @Pandya I think we have covered a relatively small number of Bhagavatam verses with our questions, but one or more of the Mukhya Upanishads may be more fruitful.

Comment: How about creating a progress report of our site?

Answer (score 10):

The Bhagavad Gita

- Chapter 1

[Why did Duryodhana mention specific warrior names in the Bhagwat Gita, Chapter-1?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6603/36)

[What was the significance of blowing (sounding of) the transcendental conch-shells in the Kurukshetra war?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6611/36)

[Why is Kripacharya known as 'Samitinjaya'](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10146/36)

[Why are there two versions of Chapter 1 - Verse 8 of Bhagavad Geetha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10246/36)

[What sort of questions perplexed Prince Arjuna before the start of the Mahabharata War](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15380/36)

[What is the importance of 1st chapter in Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19296/5212)

- Chapter 2

[How can a soul enjoy or suffer when it is not harmed by anything?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5440/36)

[Understanding Bhagavad Gita 2.46, 2.47](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6647/36)

[Why do scriptures use trivial examples?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8643/36)

[What is the actual interpretation of following Bhagavad Gita shlokha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9169/36)

[Why a positive emotion like happiness is not encouraged by Krishna in Geetha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9483/36)

[regarding permanence of matter and earthly life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10960/36)

[Has Krishna said explicitly how to measure spiritual advancement?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11644/36)

[Why does 'Yogakshema' word has different context in BG 2.45 and BG 9.22](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14005/36)

[Which characters in Mahabharata and Mahabharata war are fit in definition of 'Yoga'](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14006/36)

[Is Vishnu present in the current time?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14722/36)

- Chapter 3

[Who was the preceptor of Seeradhwaj King Janak?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5468/36)

[What is the relation between Attraction(राग) and Repulsion(द्वेष)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6701/36)

[What are the Yagnas Sri Krishna was referring to in Srimad Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9042/36)

[Is the Sankhya Darshana/Philosophy prior to Bhagavad Gita and Upanishads?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15363/36)

[On verses, from major Hindu texts, similar in purport to those found in the Bhagawat Gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15754/36)

[Why is it said in Vedanta that you are not the doer of any action?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16921/36)

[How do Vedic fire rituals like Yajnas and agnihotra help the environment?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17314/36)

- Chapter 4

[Why previous births are only known to God and not to humans?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6632/36)

[Does Krishna really love any one?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8423/36)

[Why wasn't Bhagavad Gita available at the time of Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8795/36)

[Why did Sri Krishna advice Arjuna to do service to other Saints, for gaining knowledge?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9220/36)

[Meaning of inaction in action and action in inaction in Bhagavadgita 4.18](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11527/36)

[What is the meaning of worshiping a demigod? And is it bad to worship a demigod? [BG 4.12]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11676/36)

[Bhagavad Geeta 4.14 - How can no work affect Krishna if everything is in Him and He is in everything?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15824/36)

[BG 4.40 - What does Kṛṣṇa mean by saṁśayātmā (doubting mind)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16368/36)

- Chapter 5

[Bhagavad Geeta 5.4 - Can one attain samādhi by practicing science?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16202/36)

[what is the meaning of sacrifices and austerities in Gita chapter 5 verse 29?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/54414)

[Is taking interest from bank a sin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16278/36)

- Chapter 6
- Chapter 7

[Does Hinduism forbid worshiping idols or images of God as some of its scriptures suggest?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7683/36)

[How Lord Krishna explains on "Knowledge is power"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8623/36)

[What is the difference between living beings and dead matter according to scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14520/36)

[Regulative principles for sex life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16059/36)

[Do Yajurveda 40.9, Yajurveda 32.3 and Bhagavadgita 7.20 reject idol worship?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16259/36)

- Chapter 8

[What is called Adhibhuta (Matter)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6729/36)

[Contradictory statements in the Bhagavatam and Bhagavad-Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7586/36)

[Did Swami Vivekananda, Paramhamsa Yogananda, & Osho Rajneesh really attain Moksha according to Vedic scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8668/36)

[Where are Madhvacharya's Puranic quotes describing the path to Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8680/36)

[What happens to a person's Karma if he attains salvation at the time of his death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9091/36)

[Is every Jeeva "eternal" like the ultimate God (nirguna Brahman) or "temporary" within cycle?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11038/36)

[What is Krsna Paksh( Darkness) & Sukla Paksh(Brightness) in Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13552/36)

[Which Scriptures say that by chanting Lord's name during the time of one's death one can attain "Moksha"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16028/36)

[Is the "I / Me" beyond "Brahman"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16151/36)

[Interpreting Bhagavad Gita verse 8.16](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16421/36)

- Chapter 9

[Why Jesus Isu Christ, Guru Nanak, Buddha and Muhammad should not be considered as Lord Vishnu's avatars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3402/36)

[I am confused between two shlokas of the Bhagvad Geeta, Bg 9.23 & Bg 9.25](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8735/36)

[What is the meaning of "supreme personality of godhead"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9225/36)

[Worship of one god and worship of Shri Ram](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12156/36)

[Why some Hindu Scriptures are against women?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18598/36)

[Does Geeta have gender and caste discrimination verses?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18893/36)

- Chapter 10

[Krishna said in Bhagawad Gita that He is Rama among the weapon wielders. Whom was He referring to Rama (or) Parasurama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8913/36)

[Why did Sri Krishna say he was VAJRA among weapons?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9111/36)

[Why is Indra called vAsava?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9145/36)

[Why did Sri Krishna say he is Indra among Devatas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9148/36)

[Why Marichi is called Maruts?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10463/36)

[Why Krishna says He is Sama Veda among Vedas in Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10822/36)

[If Brahman is everything, then why does Krishna (Brahman) describe himself as "best of things" in Bhagavadgita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11090/36)

[How and when did Arjuna conquer sleep?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11215/36)

[How does dvaita theory counteract/explain BG 10:20](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13569/36)

[Why Lord Krishna says he is Bhrigu in sages?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16717/36)

- Chapter 11

[Is Hinduism religious philosophy mono-theistic (Paratma) or bi-theistic (Prakriti and Purush)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2170/36)

[How is 'Vishwa Virat Swaroop' of Lord Krishna described in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7654/36)

[Did Sri Krishna really show Viswarupa Darshan to Arjuna or was it merely a projection of Arjuna's mind?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9024/36)

- Chapter 12

[Why does Krishna consider/believe the devotee who worship him as saguna superior than who worship as nirguna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11520/36)

- Chapter 13

[Chapter-13, Verse-34: Why Lord Krishna says "... Sun alone lightens the whole universe ..."?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5447/36)

[What is the seed of desire as per scripture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11631/36)

- Chapter 14

[BG 14.8 - What is the source of the scriptural definition of "mode of ignorance"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16355/36)

- Chapter 15

[How do the Bhagavad Gita and the Brahma Sutras refer to each other?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3999/36)

[More information about the idea of Asvattha, the tree of transmigration found in Chapter 15 of Bhagavad Gita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14211/36)

[What is the "param dhama" that Lord Krishna refers to in Bhagavadgita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16882/36)

- Chapter 16
- Chapter 17
- Chapter 18

[What is the difference between sacrifice (yajna) and charity (dana)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/196/36)

[What is 'Tapa' in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2498/36)

[Why does only Uppiliappan have "Mam Ekam Saranam Vraja" written on his hand?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6504/36)

[How does the non-believer profit from the Bhagavat Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9524/36)

[What are the major texts of Shaivites?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10044/36)

[How do I know what the will of God is, if I want to surrender to it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12426/36)

[Prapatti-Yog (Surrender) is higher than Bhakti ,Karma & Gyan Yog?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12512/36)

[How Four Natures created which are described in Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13630/36)

[What is the Yogeshwara form of God Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15099/36)

["Sarva Dharman Parityejya Mamekam Sharanam Vraja..." in Shiva Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15840/36)

[Explanation of SrimadBhagwadGita verse 18.66](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15998/36)

[How many types of Vaishnava Charama Shloka(s) exist?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18095/36)

So people don't seem to have much interest in  - Chapters 6, 16, and 17.

Answer (score 7):

Vyasa's Brahma Sutras

- Adhyaya 1 Pada 1

  [Does Adi Shankaracharya equate Brahman with the causal body in his Brahma Sutra Bhashya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6558/36)

  [What Chandogya Upanishad verse is the sevenfold discipline of Bhakti Yoga related to?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9325/36)

  [What is Ramanujacharya's argument that the Upanishads must be true if they grant Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11143/36)

  [Is Maya superior to Brahman as per Advaita philosophy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11295/36)
- Adhyaya 1 Pada 2

  [Why did Vedvyasa mention his shishya Jamini's opinion/saying in Brahma Sutra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14022/36)
- Adhyaya 1 Pada 3

  [Do characters in the same Brahmavidya always have the same caste?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8682/36)

  [Are the Nishada and Rathakara castes eligible for the Vedas and Jnana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10888/36)

  [Why does Adi Shankaracharya think Rig Veda 10.71.3 verse implies the Vedas are eternal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11809/36)

  [From which scripture does Adi Shankara quote about Maheswara shaping name and forms of all beings from the words of Veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19132/36)
- Adhyaya 1 Pada 4

  [Why do some Shaiva Siddhantins believe the Shwetashwatara Upanishad contradicts the Brahma Sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10296/36)
- Adhyaya 2 Pada 1

  [lokavat tu lila kaivalyam [Brh. Su. - 2.1.33] - The creation is merely a sport of Brahman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6813/36)

  [What scriptures say cranes can become pregnant without the involvement of males?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15583/36)

  [What scriptures describe scorpions born from cow dung?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17845/36)

  [What scriptures describe worms born from honey?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17940/36)

  [Why does Adi Shankaracharya say magical powers can only be obtained through the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18595/36)
- Adhyaya 2 Pada 2

  [Which Shaivite sect believes God is the operator of the Universe but not the source?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8872/36)

  [What was Madhvacharya's argument against the Shaktas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9471/36)

  [How many Shaivite commentaries on the Brahma Sutras are there?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10162/36)

  [How do Shaivite philosophers interpret the Brahma Sutras' criticism of the Shaiva Agamas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10235/36)

  [Do the Pancharatra Agamas ever say that Vishnu is the operator of the Universe but not the source?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10278/36)

  [Do any commentators other than Adi Shankaracharya disagree with both Pancharatra and Shaiva Agamas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10624/36)

  [Who is the Bhashyakara who pretended to criticize Pancharatra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15800/36)
- Adhyaya 2 Pada 3

  [How do the Bhagavad Gita and the Brahma Sutras refer to each other?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3999/36)

  [How has the Vedanta school refuted Mimamsa arguments for multiple omnipresent souls?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19327/36)
- Adhyaya 2 Pada 4

  [Why does the word "Atma" in the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad refer to the mind rather than the actual Atma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11670/36)
- Adhyaya 3 Pada 1

  [Did Adi Shankaracharya support animal sacrifice?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4118/36)

  [Do any commentaries on the Brahma Sutras say that animal sacrifice is immoral?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7947/36)

  [Did the Samkhya school believe that animal sacrifice is an easily remedied sin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19626/36)
- Adhyaya 3 Pada 2

  [What does Madhvacharya mean by the Jiva "half-entering" Brahman during fainting?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15038/36)

  [Why does the Jiva reside in Brahman during deep sleep?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15044/36)
- Adhyaya 3 Pada 3

  [Where does the Mahabharata say that liberated souls worship Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11229/36)

  [Where is the Sama Veda quote referenced in the Brahma Sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11285/36)

  [What scriptures describe Brahma's son Sanatkumara being reborn as Shiva's son Kartikeya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11298/36)

  [How does Ramanujacharya interpret a quote from Upavarsha's ancient Vritti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14552/36)

  [Interpreting Bhagavad Gita verse 8.16](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16421/36)

  [Does Adi Shankaracharya believe the existence of the soul requires scripture to establish?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18271/36)

  [What arguments does Shabara's Mimamsa Sutra Bhashya take from the Brahma Sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18275/36)

  [What is the context of an important Sutra from Sankarsha Kanda manuscripts?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18606/36)
- Adhyaya 3 Pada 4

  [Is Vishnu's incarnation Dattatreya quoted in the Brahma Sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11331/36)
- Adhyaya 4 Pada 1

  [What were the Vedic stories recited during the Ashwamedha Yagna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6966/36)

  [What is the (potentially lost) text of the Jabalas quoted by Adi Shankaracharya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7612/36)
- Adhyaya 4 Pada 2
- Adhyaya 4 Pada 3

  [Why does Adi Shankaracharya use "going to Brahman" metaphor in discussing why Brahman cannot be gone to?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8646/36)

  [Does Ramanujacharya believe that inhabitants of Brahmaloka attain Moksha when they die?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8653/36)
- Adhyaya 4 Pada 4

  [Do Thenkalai Sri Vaishnavas believe that liberated souls have powers of creation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3806/36)

So no Sutras in Adhyaya 4 Pada 2 have been asked about so far. I may remedy that though!