# What have you learnt from this site?

Tags: discussion, community

I learnt how unimaginably vast Hindu scripture is.  I disagree with a lot of it - but the vastness of whats out there is hard to comprehend.

Comment: Also take a look at: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/892/what-misconceptions-did-you-have-about-hinduism-before-joining-the-site

Comment: How irony is they have been debating over subtlity of material causes, efficient causes etc yet find difficult to understand gross differences between 'misconception before joining' Vs 'learnt from this site'.

Comment: How irony as they ask questions on moksha, all philosophies etc., yet find difficult in simply writing up question clearly in the body and the difference between 'closing questions on main site and meta site'.

Comment: The question asks what have we learnt and then gives what he has learnt about Hinduism. The question linked also says what they have learnt after joining the site. If there is any difference between two questions, one should write in the body that they are also looking for non religious concepts they have learnt on this site. Questions on meta need not to be exact duplicates.  Some times similar questions are closed as duplicates and in other cases, exact dupes are also left open if they are about site evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

When I joined this site I was having some technical queries/doubts and I mistook this site as a panel of experts who are capable of answering such queries.

But I did not take much time to realize that that was not the case.

So, to be very frank, so far, I have not learned anything NEW from this site ... By NEW I mean something spectacularly new about the religion which I consider worthy of knowing or which I am interested in knowing or which has changed my way of thinking with regards to religious/spiritual matters ..

But I really like the question-answer discussions/sessions that we have here .. And this is without doubt the best site of it's kind.

Comment: Thats because YOU are one of the experts @rickross :-)

Comment: @SK The only expert. There are no other experts on the site like he says in his answer.

Comment: Haha .. I hv never claimed myself as an expert .. I have ALWAYS said in comments that IM NOT ONE .. Thr is a Q on the Meta already "Do we hv experts?" You can see whether I hv answered it not ... It is foolish for someone to claim that he is an expert here.. my field of expertise is different and I am just a newbie in Hinduism .. Whn I said I hv not learned anything new that does not mean that I know everything .. it only means whatever I don't knw is yet to be posted here ... @SK Besides I hv also defined what I meant by NEW

Comment: Check [this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29269/are-pramanas-mentioned-in-the-vedas#comment87651_29274) for e.g. ... and I hv always said the same if the opportunity presents itself ... I hv lil bit of knowledge abt the subject and which is sufficient enough to know that it is sheer foolishness and arrogance to say "I am an expert" given the vastness of the subject's domain ... @SK

Answer (score -1):

I have learnt from this site

Positives:

a) How much learned can some individuals be
b) How much intelligent can some individuals be
c) How much dedicated can some individuals be
d) How much hard working can some individuals be
5)How inquisitive some individuals can be
6) How much kind can some individuals be.

**I have really been very very enriched within few days visiting this wonderful site.**

Negatives

Unfortunately I also learnt

a) how shamfully  dogmatic can some individuals  be
b) how foolish  can few individuals  be (like explaining our scriptures without basic knowledge of sanskrit
c) how much full of cruelty and hatred very few individuals can be because of religion.

Above all this site has made it more clear to me:

"No one becomes wise by reading many books, only learning  the two and half letters प्रेम (Love of God) alone makes a man wise. (kabir).

"learning of too much scriptures is useless. One has to attain devotion to God. Vultures fly high gazing at the filthy things (Sri Ramakrishna)

"The knowledge of the pundits is for Bhukti, not for Mukti" (Sri Adi Sankaracharyya)

May I always remember the three above sayings is my heart's prayer to God.

My sincere regards to all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89120/discussion-on-answer-by-partha-banerjee-what-have-you-learnt-from-this-site).